# Deleting items from a list according to items in another list

Tags: java

Suppose I have an `ArrayList` of `Child` objects called `children`.

```
ArrayList<Child> children = new ArrayList<>(data);
```

Now I have a List of integers which are some of the index for children in `children`.

```
List<Integer> items = new ArrayList<>(data2);
```

What would be the most efficient method to delete all children in `children` that have indexes that match integers in `items`?

Comment: How big are those lists, roughly?

Comment: Can you please provide the `Child` class code?

Comment: @atishshimpi Why is that necessary?

Comment: If your class has different parameters so need to iterate over the array list of child and match the indexes with integer list

Comment: Would be helpful to post what show what you have tried first, instead of just asking for the answer.

Comment: And by `index` do you mean array indices? Like `items` will contain an `index` for an item in the `children` array that should be removed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If items is not sorted (greater value first): `Collections.sort(items, Collections.reverseOrder());`

Then:

```
for (Integer i : items) {
    children.remove(i);
}
```

Comment: This obviously looks like the best answer as there is no shifting and sorting is probably done via quicksort which is efficient.

Answer (score 3):

You could create a list of objects to remove, then use ArrayList's `removeAll()` method.

Try something like this:

```
ArrayList<Child> toRemove = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
    toRemove.add(children.get(items.get(i)));
}

children.removeAll(toRemove);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: so you want to create a list for the "toBeRemoveElements" and delete from the original list, the "toBeRemoveElements". That's a bit backwards... don't mind me saying.

Comment: It seems a little backwards, but it eliminates the need to spend time checking every single object in the original list. Rather, you are able to remove only the necessary objects from the original list.

Comment: Very elegant. I will accept this answer if nothing better pops up.

Comment: @BinoyBabu What exactly are you expecting to become better than this?

Comment: I don't see why in this case you wouldn't just create a new list with all the items that match and instead of removing from the original list, especially if the size is 0-20 as mentioned above.

Comment: @MikeKobit I agree that with a small list, as suggested in this use case, that creating a new list and checking each element would be fine, but when I wrote my answer I was not aware of the size of the lists. That being said, I suppose I should have refreshed the comments before posting...

Comment: @cschieb I guess it is more directed at the original asker (question author? question originator? What are 'those' people called?) as to why he needs to remove from this list in place rather than filter down into a new list.

Answer (score 1):

The best approach is to create a new list with the elements that pass your condition.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to aurelianus' answer above, to consider for your use case:

Sort the items array, then remove the Child objects from the children array in descending order of the indexes.

Cost considerations:

- sorting the list of indexes - depends on the number of indexes to remove whether that's a concern.
- For every Child object removed all children with higher indexes are shifted by one in the backing array. I suspect this is done with a System.arraycopy(), which would be quite efficient. Still, the cost rises with the number of elements to remove and the number of children with higher indexes.
- memory is used in-place.

Comment: Sorting the indexes from greater to lesser removes the problem of shifting.

Comment: Unfortunately not, since each call to children.remove(int index) will shift all remaining children above the current index down by one. Sorting is required to be functionally correct so to remove the correct Child objects before changing their index.

Comment: But you are not going to remove children above it because the indexes are ordered in descending order.

Comment: Each call to children.remove(i) shifts all Child objects with index j>i down by one: see e.g.: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b27/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.remove%28int%29

Comment: Yes, but that isn't a problem because successive removes will be under such indexes.

Comment: Correct, that's why it's functionally required. Otherwise the wrong Child objects would get removed.
Under cost considerations, though, it's still relevant.

Answer (score 1):

In favor of creating a new, filtered list and treating the old list as immutable, here is how you could do that in Java 8:

```
List<Child> collect = IntStream.range(0, children.size())
            .filter(i -> !items.contains(i))
            .mapToObj(children::get)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```